# "site:nodepm.com" Results in Keywords List in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

So I have several client websites whose Google Analytics reports list organic search keywords that include "cdn site:nodepm.com"

**Some examples**

- randstream cdn site:nodepm.com
- friendly-errors-webpack-plugin cdn
  site:nodepm.com
- atropa-jslint cdn site:nodepm.com
- ast-types-flow cdn site:nodepm.com

From what I can tell, filtering for the client hostname seems to eliminate this traffic.

Is anyone else encountering this issue? What have you done to mitigate these results? Any insight as to what's creating this "traffic"?